# Is $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z^*$ a group under this operation $(a,b) + (c,d) = (ad+bc, bd).$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Denote by $\mathbb Z^*$ the set $\mathbb Z \backslash \{0\}$. Define an operation $+$ on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z^*$ by 
$$(a,b) + (c,d) = (ad+bc, bd).$$

Is $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z^*$ a group under this operation?

I really am unsure of what elements would exist in this group so that I can do the actual proof of this. I would appreciate any direction so that I can show the closure of this group.

Comment: If we wrote $(a,b)$ as $\frac{a}{b}$ ...

Comment: @DerekElkins The problem is that you have many inequivalent representations of the same number - $(1,1)$ is 'the same as' $(2,2)$ but produces different results.  You can't mod out by the equivalence relation.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Indeed, I didn't say to divide just a notational change.

Comment: Hints; (1) What does an identity have to look like in this set?  Note that you must have $(a,b)+e = (a,b)$ for all elements $(a,b)$ - you should find that this uniquely determines your identity.  (2) Now that you have that identity, can you show that many elements don't have inverses?

Answer (score 2):

Assume it is indeed a group. Then it has an identity element $e$, say $e=(c,d)$. For every (a,b) you have $(a,b)=(a,b)+(c,d)=(ad+bc,bd)$. Then $d=1$ because $b\neq 0$, and then $bc=0$, which implies $c=0$.

Therefore your identity element should be $(0,1)$. But (1,2) has no inverse, because there is no $d\in\mathbb{Z}^*$ such that $2d=1$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is a commutative monoid:

- For all $x,y$, $x+y=y+x$;
- For all $x,y,z$, $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$;
- It has a unit, namely $(0,1)$: for all $x$, $x+(1,0)=(1,0)+x=x$;

However it does not have inverses. Indeed, suppose the element $(0,2)$ has an inverse $(a,b)$, so that
$$(0,1)=(0,2)+(a,b)=(2a,2b)$$
In particular, $1=2b$, an absurd.

Answer (score 0):

We see that for
$(a,b),(c,d) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^*,$
$$(a,b) + (c,d) = (ad+bc,bd),$$
by closure integer multiplication and addition, $ad+bc \in \mathbb{Z},$ and
since $b \in \mathbb{Z}^* \wedge d \in \mathbb{Z}^* \implies
b \neq 0 \wedge d \neq 0 \implies bd \neq \implies bd \in \mathbb{Z}^*.$ Thus,
closure under $+$ holds.

We see that for $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^*,$
$$((a,b)+(c,d)) + (e,f)
= (ad+bc,bd) + (e,f)
= ((ad+bc)f + (bd)e, bdf)
= (fad+bcf+bde,bdf)
= (a,b) + (cf+de,df)$$
$$=(a,b) + ((c,d) + (e,f)).$$
Thus, associativity holds.

Consider $(0,1) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^*,$ and consider
$(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^*$. Note that
$$(a,b) + (0,1) = (a(1)+b(0),b(1)) = (a,b)
=((0)b+(1)a,(1)b) = (0,1) + (a,b).$$
Thus, the identity element exists.

Consider $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^*,$ and let
$(a,b)^{-1} = (\frac{-a}{b^2},\frac{1}{b})$. Note that this is in the set since
$b \neq 0 \implies \frac{1}{b} \neq 0.$ We see that
$$(a,b) + (\frac{-a}{b^2},\frac{1}{b})
= (\frac{a}{b} + \frac{-ab}{b^2},b\frac{1}{b})
= (\frac{a}{b} - \frac{-a}{b},1) = (0,1)$$
$$= (\frac{-ab}{b^2} + \frac{a}{b},\frac{1}{b}b)
= (\frac{-a}{b^2},\frac{1}{b}) + (a,b).$$

Thus, the existence of inverses holds. Hence, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}^*$
under your definition of $+$ is a group.

Comment: $(\frac{-a}{b^2},\frac{1}{b})\notin\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}^*$ for $b\neq\pm 1$